# Only show checked items angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a page with check boxes on it and I am trying to redisplay the items the user has checked in the basket as they check.

This happens but if they uncheck the items dont remove from the basket. Can you help?

```
<table class="products-table-class">

            <tr>
                <th>News</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{     category: 'News' }" >


                <td>{{ product.product }}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ids[product.product]"></td>
            </tr>



</table>
 <div class="featured-info">
      <h3>Basket</h3>

      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in ids ">{{key}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is 'product.product'? you can just store the checked value as a property of product, then use an ng-if 'product.checked' in the list item

Comment: products is a row from a db table, the product row also has a product field... agree could be better named. Something like product.name would make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you issue here is in your ids object. When the user unchecks a checkbox angular does not remove it from the object. It simple changes the value to true or false.

```
{
   '123' : true,
   '1234' : false
}
```

So the product will never get removed from the basket. You can add an ng-if on the ng-repeat to check if the value is true.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in ids " ng-if="value === true">{{key}}</li>
```

The value might be a string instead of a boolean so it could look like this. I can't remember of the top of my head.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in ids " ng-if="value === 'true'">{{key}}</li>
```

Also here is the link to the angular docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: thanks a lot! this place is great - you really saved my bacon!

Comment: Glad to be able to help.